# Ruby: class in different files but using each other

Tags: ruby

In one of my projects, I need to put two class definitions in one file, and their parent class in another. After I required the parent file, it's still giving `uninitialized constant Foo`. Checkout the code below. The problem is: How to make it work(run from file2)?

```
#file1.rb
require_relative './file2.rb' 

class Bar < Foo
  get('/bar') { 'bar' }
end
class Car < Foo
end

#file2.rb
require_relative './file1.rb'

class Foo 
  get('/foo') { 'foo' }
end
class Dar < Foo
  Bar.new
  Car.new
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is about circular dependency in this problem, but I do figure out a way to avoid the bug. Use another file require both files, and execute from the new file.

```
#file1.rb
class Bar < Foo
  get('/bar') { 'bar' }
end
class Car < Foo
end

#file2.rb
class Foo 
  get('/foo') { 'foo' }
end
class Dar < Foo
  Bar.new
  Car.new
end

#file_root.rb
require './file1'
require './file2'
```

FYI, you probably already figured out I'm using Sinatra from the 'get' method. So the `file_root.rb` file will actually be the `config.ru`.

Answer (score 0):

Define your parent classes first and your derived ones second. This also makes your code a lot easier to navigate since it's in a predictable order, prerequisites first, specializations later.

Defining it last is impossible, Ruby absolutely needs to know what `Foo` is first. You can get away with stubbing it in, though:

```
class Foo
end

class Bar < Foo
end

class Foo
  # Re-open class and add functionality
  get('...)
end
```

I'd recommend steering away from this approach whenever possible. It usually ends up accumulating code in both places and nasty duplication errors can occur.

Comment: I totally agree with the benefits doing so, but the problem is, in my case, the Foo class is in another file, and in Bar's file can't find Foo definition.

Comment: Then you'll need to `require_relative` on that file first.

Comment: Yes, I did. Then the problem leads to the code I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Do you have a circular dependency, perhaps?